# Can't disable a tkiner Button while in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Basically, I am currently writing a python program (technically its a game) in which a certain (TKinter Widget) button should only be able to be clicked every 1 second. here is an example of what I mean:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
def button_click():
    button["state"] = DISABLED
    print("button clicked! Please wait 1 second...")
    time.sleep(1)
    button["state"] = NORMAL

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=button_click)

button.pack() #Please Dont Tell Me Not To Use Pack() ; I Use Place()
```

So anyways, for example, when running this program, if I just keep clicking the button, it will increase the count by 1 each second. instead, I would like it to not count all the clicks that happen between the first click, and 1 second after that.

Comment: Don't use `sleep()` in tkinter applications as it interferes with `mainloop()` — use its [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) universal widget method instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the tkinter does not take control when the button is disabled, so it is not updated.  You need to call, for example, `button.update()` after it is disabled to force the update:

```
def button_click():
    button["state"] = DISABLED
    button.update() # force the update
    print("button clicked! Please wait 1 second...")
    time.sleep(1)
    button["state"] = NORMAL
```

---

However, it is better to use `after()` instead of `time.sleep()`:

```
def button_click():
    button["state"] = DISABLED
    print("button clicked! Please wait 1 second...")
    # enable the button after one second
    button.after(1000, lambda: button.config(state='normal'))
```

Comment: Even Though This Partially Works (And I Upvoted It For That), Somehow even what the button appears to be disabled, it will still register 1-2 Extra Clicks.

Comment: I don't have that issue if `after()` is used.

Comment: oh let me try that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot the "root.mainloop" at the end of the code.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
def button_click():
    button["state"] = DISABLED
    print("button clicked! Please wait 1 second...")
    time.sleep(1)
    button["state"] = NORMAL

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=button_click)

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This works for me. You can only press the button every 1 second.

Comment: In my example, I forgot to put the root.mainloop().

Comment: Yeah you can only click the button after 1 second, but you also can't do anything else for a second. Clicking that button will lock up everything for one second.